# Nginx proxy_pass block client header and force nginx to use custom header

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx config where I take the cookie to use with this config;

```
        proxy_set_header Authorization $token;
```

But if the client put in custom header Authorization this overwrites as I see it the config one. Is it possible to block the client header while using proxy and use my customised header based on variable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You can use

```
proxy_hide_header "Authorization";
proxy_set_header Authorization $token;
```

Or if you want no headers coming from client then you can do below

```
proxy_pass_request_headers off;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out.

Comment: According to the [`proxy_hide_header` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header), this directive is used to block *response* headers from being sent back to the client, which is not the case the OP asked about.

Comment: @dubek, thanks for pointing that out, seems I mis-judged the usage. And since I never got feedback from OP there was no chance to improve the answer. Did the other approach `proxy_pass_request_headers off;` work for you?